# PubSubException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, scala, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

folks, I am getting the following error message using Pubsub:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.pubsub.PubSubException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR
>   Received Goaway
>   max_age
>   ....
>   Caused by: com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: HTTP/2 error code: NO_ERROR

It happens like once an hour, we are using google-cloud-pubsub 0.8.0, google-cloud-storage 0.7.0 and scala 2.11.7. Anyone can give some help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [GOAWAY](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#GOAWAY) frame from the server indicates that the server is shutting down the connection. You can try asking on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/ for more details on why this is happening for this particular service, but max_age is perhaps a hint that the connection is reaching a certain time limit. The correct response is to reconnect (shutdown the gRPC channel and create a new one) when this error is received.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your response! I will reach out to the GCP github

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and the problem was that I was using different library versions on the services communicating through grpc.
The library which caused the problem is this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>proto-google-common-protos</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope it helps!